# Looking for a tool for managing complex powershell automation processes with multiple scripts

Tags: sql-server, powershell, tools, automation

Sysadmin here,

I'm wondering what tools you all use to manage large scale automation tasks with powershell. I currently have several powershell scripts that are regularly used, but do not interact or call each other. I'm looking for a GUI interface to help make sense of it, and grab variables as outputs from one script into another.

I can do all this through powershell alone, but wondering if there's a more visual way to set up the complex interactions between scripts.

An example of a process that would need to be completed:

1. SQL backup taken on hosted client server
2. Backup uploaded to FTP Site
3. Backup loaded to data scrubbing server
4. Backup restored to local SQL Instance
5. Client sensitive info scrubbed
6. Backup taken and uploaded to NAS
7. NAS backup restored to local support environment
8. Database modified to add users for WinAuth
9. Various server config on support environment for our software

Comment: Given you can call CLR resources from Powershell it pretty easy to build a simple GUI directly in Powershell - a web search should find you plenty of resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you two things:

- With a GUI: https://www.minionware.net/
- Without a GUI: https://dbatools.io/